# Ranicki symmetric L-groups of finite fields?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Can anyone tell me what the Ranicki symmetric L-groups $L^*(F)$ are when $F$ is a finite field? (and maybe provide a reference?) Thanks!

Comment: This is a question which interests me a lot!

Comment: Hi Greg, i retagged this to what I thought you meant. As it stood, this question seemed to be the only one with those tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The symmetric $L$-group $L^*(F)$ of a field $F$ are 4-periodic, 
$$L^n(F)=L^{n+4}(F)$$
by Proposition 7.1 of 
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ats1.pdf

$L^{2i}(F)$ is the Witt group of $(-)^i$-symmetric forms:
see Milnor and Husemoller!

$L^{2i+1}(F)=0$, see 
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/simple.pdf
(my shortest paper).